# Adding integer using combineByKey is adding them to lists

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a map function that creates a key-value pair of type [Tuple, Integer] but when I use combineByKey to add the integer values, it creates a tuple of those integers instead of adding them.

I have tried typecasting the integer but it does not help.

```py
def subset_from_kv(para):
    sol = []

    para_new = (i for i in (para and ff))
    # print(list(para))
    tt = (itertools.combinations(sorted(para_new), size))

    for j in tt:
        flag = True

        for i in list(itertools.combinations(list(j), size-1)):

            if (i not in (frequent_itemset_val)):
                flag = False

                break
        if flag is True:
            sol.append(j)

    return sol


rdd1_values = rdd1_original.values()

rdd_inter = rdd1_values.mapPartitions(lambda t: subset_from_kv(t)).map(lambda x: (x, 1))

new_item_rdd_size_i = rdd_inter.combineByKey(
    lambda value: (value),
    lambda x, y: (x + y),
    lambda x, y: (x, y)
)
```

`rdd_inter.collect()` gives:

```
[(('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-4TMQnQJW1yd6NqGRDvAeA'), 1), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-6h3K1hj0d4DRcZNUtHDuw'), 1), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-6tvduBzjLI1ISfs3F_qTg'), 1), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-9eNGMp8XiygI8t8QFuFWw'), 1), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-9nai28tnoylwViuJVrYEQ'), 1).....
```

**EDIT:** **I have 3 partitions**

new_item_rdd_size_i is expected to give

```
[(('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-4TMQnQJW1yd6NqGRDvAeA'),(10, 1, 3), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-6h3K1hj0d4DRcZNUtHDuw'), (12, 13, 5), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-6tvduBzjLI1ISfs3F_qTg'), (21, 7, 33), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-9eNGMp8XiygI8t8QFuFWw'), (111, 34, 14), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-9nai28tnoylwViuJVrYEQ'), (41, 33, 11)...
```

but the output is concatenating the values of 1 instead of adding them:

```
[(('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-Bdw-5H5C4AYSMGnAvmnzw'), ((1, 1), 1)), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-De4AV1Fx67mDMGrFOw44Q'), ((1, 1), 1)), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-FLnsWAa4AGEW4NgE8Fqew'), ((1, 1), 1)), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-Ht7HiGBox8lS1Y8IPjO8g'), ((1, 1), 1)), (('-050d_XIor1NpCuWkbIVaQ', '-ZBfr1BHvArFp1d6XH8jOQ'), ((1, 1), 1))]
```

Comment: Your expected output is difficult to understand. Can you explain it ?

Comment: I want my expected output to give count of the key in every partition

Answer (score 0):

according to [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.combineByKey),

```
combineByKey(
    createCombiner, 
    mergeValue, 
    mergeCombiners, 
    numPartitions=None, 
    partitionFunc=<function portable_hash>
)
```

with :

- **createCombiner**, which turns a V into a C (e.g., creates a one-element
  list)
- **mergeValue**, to merge a V into a C (e.g., adds it to the end of a
  list)
- **mergeCombiners**, to combine two C’s into a single one (e.g., merges
  the lists)

In you case :

- **createCombiner** is `lambda value: (value)` : you create a tuple
- **mergeValue** is `lambda x, y: (x + y)` : you add 2 tuples ==> 1 tuple with 2 elements
- **mergeCombiners** is `lambda x, y: (x, y)` : you create a tuple with 2 elements ...

Therefore, your final output is a tuple of tuple of tuple of tuple etc....

You should try a simpler method, like `reduceByKey`: `rdd.reduceByKey(add)`

Comment: I actually want to create a filter on value from each partition and that's why can't use reduceByKey